# The resource is not defined in ARM template . Microsoft.Datafactory/factories/integrationruntimes/IR-prod not defined

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

This my LS dependent on IR of type managed. Trying to pass IR having different name meant for the target.How to get the resourceid for IR which is not part of this template.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kusum Shaw, and welcome to stack overflow. Can I make a suggestion? Instead of linking to a screenshot, your question would be better if you include the ARM json directly in the question. Remember, on this site you're encouraged to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70503381/edit) your question to improve it as much as possible :)

Comment: Hello @Kusum Shaw, which IR is not defined in the template ? is it the IR reference that you are providing in connect via block. if thats the one , then why there is a depends on for the same IR in the template ? can you please help me understand

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

**As per the below error :**

> The resource is not defined in ARM template .
> Microsoft.Datafactory/factories/integrationruntimes/IR-prod not
> defined

If you are ***using a IR which is not in the template***, then ***you should not add a depends on block for the same IR***. As from the code you are using the `connectVia reference name` which is a IR not provided in the template and then again you are referencing the same IR in the `depends on block` as well like below :

```
"dependson": ["[concat (variables('factorylId'), '/integrationRuntimes/',parameters ('connectVia_referenceName'))]"]
```

But as the `connectVia_referenceName` is not present in the Template its throwing error not defined.

**So, you can just try removing `dependsOn` from your code and try like below :**

```
{
"name": "[concat (parameters ('factoryName'), '/example-name')]",
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
"apiversion": "2018-06-01",
"properties": {
"description": "This linked service is used to connect Synapse instance for invoking ILF stored proc",
"annotations": [],
"type": "AzureSqlDW",
"typeProperties": {
"connectionString": {
"type": "SecureString",
"value": "[parameters('connectionString')]"
}
},
"connectVia": {
"referenceName": "[parameters('connectVia_referenceName')]",
"type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
}
}
}
```